# Don't validate date fields on MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, datetime

I have a simple doubt but I wasn't able to solve it.

I have a class like above:

```
public class TB_Cliente_Fisica
{
    public int IDCliente { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public string RG { get; set; }
    public string Sexo { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime dataNascimento { get; set; }
}
```

And, in the view, I have the following code for the datetime field:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dataNascimento, new { @class = "dataNascimento", placeholder = "Data nascimento" })
```

And it is generating the following markup:

```
<input class="dataNascimento" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field dataNascimento must be a date." data-val-required="O campo dataNascimento é obrigatório." id="TB_Cliente_Fisica_dataNascimento" name="TB_Cliente_Fisica.dataNascimento" placeholder="Data nascimento" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

And when the user submits the form, it validates this field.

But I want to let the user leaves this field empty, if he wants to. How can I do it? And why is it requiring this field?

Comment: because you haven't set it to be nullable? Alternatively try 'setting' it in your model to a default value before **if(modelstate.IsValid)** is called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nullable property

```
public System.DateTime? dataNascimento { get; set; }
```

Comment: It did work! But I am generating the classes through a database using Entity Framework. If I have to modify the diagram, it will replace my changes in the class, and I'll have to update it every time, right? Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Маке field in db nullable, this will generate nullable field.

Comment: Of course, I can't believe I didn't think of that.. Thanks for the help! :)